# Cancelling SQL Query in background in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm designing a small desktop app that fetches data from SQL server. I used `BackgroundWorker` to make the query execute in background. The code that fetches data generally comes down to this:

```
public static DataTable GetData(string sqlQuery)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        c.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery))
        {
            cmd.Connection = c;
            using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                t.Load(r);
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

Since query can take up 10-15 minutes I want to implement cancellation request and pass it from GUI layer to DAL. Cancellation procedure of `BackroundWorker` won't let me cancel `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` beacuse it only stops when data is fetched from server or an exception is thrown by Data Provider. 
I tried to use `Task` and `async/await` with `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken)` but I am confused where to use it in multi-layer app (GUI -> BLL -> DAL).

Comment: If you are able to use `async` then that is definitely the way to go, but you need to be async from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [SqlCommand.Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) method ?

Aproach: encapsulate that `GetData` method in a Thread/Worker and then when you cancel/stop that thread call the `Cancel()` method on the `SqlCommand` that is being executed.

Here is an example on how to use it on a thread

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    private static SqlCommand m_rCommand;

    public static SqlCommand Command
    {
        get { return m_rCommand; }
        set { m_rCommand = value; }
    }

    public static void Thread_Cancel()
    {
        Command.Cancel();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                Command = connection.CreateCommand();
                Command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE TestCancel";
                try
                {
                    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch { }

                Command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TestCancel(co1 int, co2 char(10))";
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestCancel VALUES (1, '1')";
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TestCancel";
                SqlDataReader reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

                Thread rThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread_Cancel));
                rThread2.Start();
                rThread2.Join();

                reader.Read();
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    static private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        // To avoid storing the connection string in your code, 
        // you can retrieve it from a configuration file.
        return "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
            + "Integrated Security=SSPI";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use Thread_Cancel() method from upper layer? Can I call it when .CancellationPending property of BackgroundWorker is set?

Comment: does this help ? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can only do Cancelation checking and Progress Reporting between Distinct lines of code. Usually both require that you disect the code down to the lowest loop level, so you can do both these things between/in the loop itterations. When I wrote my first step into BGW, I had the advantage that I needed to do the loop anyway so it was no extra work. You have one of the worse cases - pre-existing code that you can only replicate or use as is.

**Ideal case:**

This operation should not take nearly as long is it does. 5-10 minutes indicates that there is something rather wrong with your design.

If the bulk of the time is transmission of data, then you are propably retreiving way to much data. Retrieving everything to do filtering in the GUI is a very common mistake. Do as much filtering in the query as possible. Usign a Distributed Database might also help with transmission performance.

If the bulk of the time is processing as part of the query operation (complex Conditions), something in your general approach might have to change. There are various ways to trade off complex calculation with a bit of memory on the DBMS side. Views afaik can cache the results of operations, while still maintaining transactional consistency.

But it really depends what your backend DB/DBMS and use case are. A lot of the use SQL as Query Language. So it does not allow us to predict wich options you have.

**Second best case:**

The second best thing if you can not cut it down, would be if you had the actually DB access code down to the lowest loop and would do progress reporting/cancelation checking on it. That way you could actually use the existing Cancelation Token System inherent in BGW.

**Everything else**

Using any other approach to Cancelation is really a fallback. I wrote a lot on why it is bad, but felt that this might work better if I focus on the core issue - likely something wrong in design of he DB and/or Query. Because those might well eliminate the issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks for detailed clarification. Unfortunately, backend is a 3rd party hardware/software, I'm not in control here. Actually it's a Historian Server storing industrial process data. MS SQL Server acts as gateway for client access to historical and statiscal data (such as my app). Query examples are given in the documentation and they are also very specific.

Comment: The main problem is that there's a huge amount of calculation being performed on server side when querying statistic data. I can only narrow down date/time period and decrease the number of process parameters in my query in order to make server response time more appropriate.

Comment: @AntonN.: If you can not control the backend, just wrap your own backend around it. Do not query the original source. Query your own DB wich caches the results from the Original one. As it is historical/archive data, changes should be uncommon in all but the newest entries. And once you query your own server, you have control over the Server Hardware and can use Optimisations like Views that cache some calculations. For example, DNS is a costly thing to ask at the primary servers. So in practice DNS has layers upon layers of caching Severs down the line (OS, Router, ISP).